# Conectar PHP 7.2 a SQLSERVER 2014

Tags: php, sql-server

estoy tratando de conectar mi PHP v7.2.10 a SQLServer2014 he visto bastantes tutoriales y no he logrado hacerlo, he descargado las librerías correspondientes a la versión de mi PHP(php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll,  php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll , 
   php_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll,   php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll)luego las pego en la carpeta de PHP/ext , ademas de escribir los nombre de la mismas en el PHP.ini(extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll...) reinicio el servidor y luego lo enciendo y no me carga las librerias en el PHPInfo.
me lanza el siguiente error cuando ejecuto la conexion:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\conexion.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\conexion.php on line 8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el codigo de mi conexion que estoy ejecutando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que hago en el PHP.ini y en la carpeta de EXT
.....espero puedan ayudarme :D

Comment: Sergio bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿No te funciona creando una instancia con `new`, pasando los parámetros [como explica el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php)?

Comment: me da errores como tu mencionas, y creo que es por lo mismo porque no me carga las librerias

Comment: ¿Qué errores da usando `new`, los mismos o diferentes?

Comment: Debes solo dejar una version, ya sea la **nts** o la **ts** de cada **.dll**

Comment: Tengo el mismo error con PHP 7.3

Comment: Mira en el info.php si tienes activado o no Thread Safety ya que si lo tienes activado las .dll que necesitas son las ts, solamente.

Comment: Tu error es por que no haz agregado la libreria de sqlsrv haz in php.info() y mira lo que tienes agregado sino esta sqlsrv ahi esta el problema, ref: https://www.php.net/manual/es/sqlsrv.installation.php