# Configurar Xampp para usar Laravel con pdo sqlsvr

Tags: php, sql, laravel, xampp

En mi trabajo usamos SQL Server como motor de base de datos, quiero trabajar con Laravel en su versión 5.8 y conectarlo a este sql. Se que en config/database.php se hace referencia a este motor pero igual estuve leyendo en foros que a XAMPP tengo que cargarle unas dll.

En este link encontré como se hace aunque hacen referencia una versión de php más vieja -> [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831500/connect-sqlsrv-in-xampp)

Y también encontré este otro usuario tratando de hacer lo mismo pero con php 7.2 y no le resuelven el problema [OTRO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/conectar-php-7-2-a-sqlserver-2014)

Acorde a la explicación del usuario y mis archivos deberían ser:

Como tengo en mi carpeta php **php7ts.dll** las dll que tengo que poner en la carpeta **ext** son:

- php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
- php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll

Y estas las tengo que agregar como *extension* en mi *php.ini*

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
```

Recargo Xampp y creé un archivo info.php con la instrucción phpinfo();.En la parte de las DBO no carga, tampoco me tira algún error XAMPP. De igual forma para probar configuré mi archivo **.env** con los parametros para hacer la conexión:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=aca va la ip
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=terra
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=contraseña
```

Pero claro, me tira error:

```
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from [Tab_Terminales])
```

Quisiera saber si me falta algún paso para que esto funcione u ocupar WAMPP (con este no he probado aún).

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Yo para que eso me funcionase con XAMPP tuve que poner el PHP 7.3. EL problema es que esas librerías dll no queda claro para que versión son. Yo lo que hay que poner en el php.ini lo tengo asi: extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll y es como me funcionó. Cambia lo que tienes y pega lo mio, con el ; incluido, deberia quedarte una sobre otra y la segunda empezando por ; como si estuviera comentada. También es verdad que tuve que renombrar una de las librerias como php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll, que, si no me equivoco, es la primera que pones en la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, voy a hacer la prueba y comento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que descargar y habilitar las siguientes extensiones en tu php.ini

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
```

Por defecto no vienen, pero las puedes descargar de [AQUÍ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420) y después simplemente meterlas en \xampp\php\ext y reiniciar el XAMP

Comment: Si, efectivamente probé harto pero me funcionó con los archivos que dices tu, no renombré los archivos como me muestras en tu ejemplo pero me funcionaron los que terminaban diciendo x64